# How to extract data searching by name from sqlite?

Tags: database, sqlite, search, prepared-statement

i followed a tutorial about creating sqlite database, inserting data to and searching data from it and used the method below to extract data from that db:

```
-(IBAction)findContacts{

    const char *dbpath = [databasePath UTF8String];
    sqlite3_stmt *statement;
    if (sqlite3_open(dbpath, &contactDB)==SQLITE_OK) {
        NSString *querySQL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT adress, phone FROM CONTACTS WHERE name = \"%@\"", [name text]];
        status.text = querySQL;         
        const char *query_stmt = [querySQL UTF8String];

        if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(contactDB, query_stmt, -1, &statement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK) {
            if (sqlite3_step(statement)==SQLITE_ROW) {

                NSString *adressField = [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:(const char *) sqlite3_column_text(statement, 0)];
                adress.text = adressField;

                NSString *phoneField = [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:(const char *) sqlite3_column_text(statement, 1)];
                phone.text = phoneField;

                status.text = @"Match Found";

                [adressField release];
                [phoneField release];} 

                    status.text = @"Match not Found";
                    adress.text = @"";
                    phone.text = @"";
            sqlite3_finalize(statement);}
        sqlite3_close(contactDB);}}
```

When i compile, no error! no attention! however does not work...

What i found was that because

```
sqlite3_prepare_v2(contactDB, query_stmt, -1, &statement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK)
```

was not equal, code was not getting in if statemens. i found out that when i reversed the condition with

```
sqlite3_prepare_v2(contactDB, query_stmt, -1, &statement, NULL) != SQLITE_OK)
```

and saw at status.text "match not found". but still it was not able to find any true contact inside.

did you realize anything wrong with the code?

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 1):

You really do not want to enter the block unless the result of 'sqlite3_prepare_v2' is actually SQLITE_OK.

Changing the equality requirement to '!=' was an interesting diagnostic, but clearly it is not a change that should be left permanently in your test code.

Now that we know that sqlite3_prepare_v2 does not return the code for success, the question to ask is: what code *does* it return?

According to the documentation, it must be returning one of the codes shown here:

http://sqlite.org/c3ref/c_abort.html

You can also use 'sqlite3_errmsg' to get a string representation. See: http://sqlite.org/c3ref/errcode.html

Comment: Solved by your helps. Thanks que que... :)